# Orthonormal basis of this normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

In this example,

[image]

It is saying that the 2 vectors

$ \frac{(i,1)}{ \sqrt 2} , \frac {(-i,1)}{ \sqrt 2}$

are an orthonormal basis, I wanted to verify this, so I checked the norm of each vector, the norms turned out to be $1$

But when I perform the inner product of the two vectors

$\langle \frac{(i,1)}{ \sqrt 2},\frac {(-i,1)}{ \sqrt 2}\rangle = 1$

It does not equal zero, so they should not be orthonormal, is this a typo in the book or am I missing something?

Comment: Has your book discussed the inner product on complex spaces explicitly?

Comment: If you visualize in complex plane, (i,1) is in first quadrant and (-i, 1) is in fourth quadrant separated by $\pi/2$

Comment: @ganeshie8 I don't know about you, but personally I have trouble visualizing $\Bbb C^2$ and angles between elements of that space.

Comment: @Arthur Ahh I was visualizing in $\Bbb C$. Stupid of me haha

Answer (score 2):

Inner products on complex vector spaces are customarily not entirely as straight-forward as they are for real spaces.

One of the properties we would like an inner product to have is that the inner product of a vector with itself should be a positive real number. This is clearly not the case for, say, the vector $(i,0)$ if you use the same formula as the one you're used to from real linear algebra.

The conventional inner product on complex spaces *conjugates* the first factor before computing the inner product the "real" way. For instance,
$$
\langle(i,0),(i,0)\rangle=(\bar i\cdot i)+(\bar 0\cdot0)=1
$$
Applying this to your inner product gives a result of $0$.

Comment: Oh so this is due to one of the axioms that says $\langle v,v\rangle \ge 0$ ?

I mean is this just a manipulation to satisfy the axiom or is it derived

Comment: Is the linearity in the second argument more common in theoretical math as well?

Comment: @Arthur isn't it conjugate linear in one of the arguments and linear in the other?

Comment: @Botond Yes, of course. It's still morning here. But yes, the conjugation inner product is the more common. When having to choose between positive definiteness in one hand, and pure linearity and symmetry on the other, the scales tip in favour of positive definiteness at the cost of some conjugations here and there.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\left\langle[i,1]^t,  [-i, 1]^t\right\rangle=\bar{(i)}(-i)+\bar{(1)}(1)=(-i)^2+1=0$$
The same applies when the inner product is linear in it's first argument instead of the second.

Comment: What does the superscript $t$ mean?

Comment: @khaled014z It's just the transpose of the vector.